# What does Groot's last line mean in The Guardians of the Galaxy (movie)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

Toward the end of *The Guardians of the Galaxy*

> when the *Dark Aster* is about to crash, Groot begins enfolding the rest of the team in a protective, multi-layered cocoon of branches and vines, presumably to cushion them against the impact.  When Rocket tearfully asks why he's sacrificing himself for the rest of the team, Groot slowly says, **"*We* are Groot."**
>
> Since this is very distinct and different from the rest of his dialogue, no one needs to translate it as Rocket did a few times with his other lines.

But the exact meaning of the line is a bit unclear.  Has anyone involved in the production of the movie said anything about what that line means and why he said it that way?

Comment: Is there really any other way to interpret this than "You are my friends. I will protect you, and if we die, we will all die together"?

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen it described any other way and given the context of the movie's overall theme, I can't imagine an alternate explanation.  Even for Groot.

Comment: I saw it as a joke. You hear him say "We are", which contradicts what Rockets said about him only being able to say "I", "am" and "Groot" in that order. So you expect him to say "We are friends", like the rest of them had said earlier. The joke is that the last word is again "Groot" instead.

Comment: @George: Like Drax's "metaphor" a few scenes earlier?

Comment: @MasonWheeler I'm afraid I don't remember it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'll find different iterations of the same interpretation around the web, but the one I liked best was from the [Mennonite World Review](http://mennoworld.org/2014/08/12/we-are-groot-a-kingdom-image/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140815192952/http://mennoworld.org/2014/08/12/we-are-groot-a-kingdom-image/)):

> "Groot no longer sees himself as an individual. The lives of his
> friends are now enfolded into his own. The well-being of each of them
> is not only equivalent to but above his own because this family is now
> his identity."

Groot enfolds the group around himself, itself a symbol of their joined identity. The imagery of a connected group comes up again when they all join hands when holding the infinity stone, a task that could not be taken on alone.

Comment: Agreed - this was my interpretation as well when I watched it. He was basically saying "We are family."